# encapsulation for mixin's members in Scala

Tags: scala, encapsulation, mixins, traits

Traits in Scala can be used as both mixins and interfaces. It leads to some inconsistence - if I want to close some method inside trait, I just can't do that:

```
object Library {
    protected trait A { def a: Int = 5 }
    trait B extends A { private override def a: Int = super.a }
    //I want to close `a` memeber for all traits extending B; it's still possible to open it in some another trait `C extends A`, or even `Z extends B with C`
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:10: error: overriding method a in trait A of type => Int;
 method a has weaker access privileges; it should not be private
           trait B extends A { private override def a: Int = super.a }
                                                    ^
```

Such error is totally fine from [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)-perspective as I (or compiler) may want to cast it to the supertype `A`. But if i'm just using it as mix-in I never need to do that actually, for instance in some Cake-pattern variation. I'll do something like:

```
 import Library._
 object O extends B with K with L with App
```

and that's it. I can't even access trait `A` here. I know, there is type inference which may go up to super-type, but it's just a "line of types" so compiler could just skip `A` here and go on (of course it's very very theoretical). Another example - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220838/1809978) I had to provide default implementation for method, which I don't really need.

The current solution I use is OOP-composition, but it's not so flexible (as linearization doesn't work here) and not much compatible with mix-ins concept. Some projects I've seen, they actually do mixins and have "over9000" redundand visible members. Several years ago there was an idea to "mark" such mixins composition by `with` keyword specified instead of `extends`, but can't even find that thread now.

So, is there any better practices for ad-hoc member encapsulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not general solution, but it's possible  to close methods from the outside world inside one module:

```
object Library {
  protected trait A { 
    private[Library] def a: Int = 5 
    private[Library] def b: Int = 7 
  }
  trait B extends A { 
    def b = super.b 
  }
}

import Library._
object C extends B

scala> C.a
<console>:179: error: method a in trait B cannot be accessed in object C
              C.a
                ^
scala> C.b
res131: Int = 7
```

So we're just inverting encapsulation here. If `A` should be also open for extension:

```
object Library {
  protected trait _A { 
    private[Library] def a: Int = 5 
    private[Library] def b: Int = 7 
  }
  trait B extends A { /*...*/ }
  trait A extends _A {
    override def a = super.a 
    override def b = super.b
  }
}
```

So, maybe too boilerplate, but at least it works.

P.S. The idea is partially inspired by another deleted answer which didn't work :)