# Inheritance from one trait with generic type

Tags: scala, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, traits

I have a base trait Search and two subtraits WriterSearch,BookSearch that implements that trait.

`trait Search[T]{...}`

`trait WriterSearch extends Search[Writer]{...}`

`trait BookSearch extends Search[Book]{...}`

`trait AllSearch extends WriterSearch with BookSearch`
AllSearch does not work. The reason is *...inherits different type instances of trait....*. The AllSearch will be empty just I need to combine all traits. When I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213608/how-to-mixin-different-type-instances-of-same-trait-in-scala), it says overriding `type T in trait BookSearch with bounds <: Book` How can I solve that?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you provided. Does your code actually look like this?

Comment: Sorry I forget to add the problem.

Comment: @gggg
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213608/how-to-mixin-different-type-instances-of-same-trait-in-scala

Comment: I tried but  this error ` AllSearch inherits different type instances of ..`  is occurred.

Comment: @gggg You can try one of approaches https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/c75df4d66e280d792a72ab40b3890e16

Comment: I did not work when I tested : `found   : org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[....[_1]]
[error]  required: org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[Book]]`